# Does my routine adversely affect me?

Tags: workout-routines, strength-training, beginners

I am a 15 year old male, and I started exercising about 6 months ago. However I managed to procure a pair of dumbbells at the beginning of April, and have been exercising with them so far. My question is whether my following routine has any adverse effects on me? Also I have read that the abdominals work in converse(?) to the lower back and the back in general. So is there enough lower back work in my routine, as compared to the rest?

I warmup with around 5 minutes of on-the-spot jogging/jumping jacks/jumping rope, and do around of dynamic stretching for all major muscle groups.

- Bodyweight shoulder tap pushup x20 / 7.5kg(per arm) dumbbell flies x10 / 7.5kg(per arm) dumbbell bench press x10
- Bodyweight pullup x10 / 7.5kg(per arm) dumbbell row
- Bodyweight bench dips x10
- 7.5kg(per arm) dumbbell hammer curl x10
- 7.5kg(per arm) dumbbell squat x10
- 7.5kg(per arm) dumbbell military press x10
- 10kg(per arm) dumbbell deadlift x5

I do each of these  exercises in a row without rest, then rest for about 1-2 minutes, then start another such "superset". I do 3 of these.

Afterwards, I stretch all my muscle groups for about 30 seconds-1 min per group. And then I start an ab and calf routine that goes like this:

- 2.5 kg weighted plate crunch x10
- Standing calf raise with 7.5kg(per arm) x20
- Lying leg raises x10
- Standing calf raise with 7.5kg(per arm) x15
- 1.25 kg weighted plate twist crunch x10
- Standing calf raise with 7.5kg(per arm) x10
- Plank 30 seconds
- Standing calf raise with 7.5kg(per arm) x10
- 5kg russian twist x8(per side)

Comment: How difficult do you find your routine?

Comment: Any specific exercises that are easier or harder?

Answer (score 2):

Initially, what you're doing is just fine for starting out, but the problem *will* arise that you won't be progressing past a certain point.

You have a set of dumbbells and that's great, but what will you do when you should be increasing the weight? You're already managing 10-20 reps with the weight you have, but in order to stimulate progress in strength and size, you should be increasing the resistance by adding more weight.

If you're just doing the same workout with the same weight over and over, you will stagnate really fast, because your body will simply get used to going through the motions. For progress, variety is alpha and omega. Whether it be variety in weight/resistance, or set/rep scheme.

If you want to continue working out at home, I'd strongly suggest getting your hands on some incremental dumbbells, which means they let you add/remove weight in ranges. But even then, it's a very limited tool.

Also, there's the issue of all the muscles you aren't getting to isolate. I hate for this answer to be so negative, but a gym will resolve all these issues, and given that you're starting at such a young age, you'll thank yourself for doing it soon enough.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by muscles that op is not working out.  He seems to be getting a fairly all round workout to me

Comment: @LightMikeE - Yeah, like I said, initially this is going to be just fine. But if he keeps doing the same routine over and over, there is *always* going to be some muscles that are not getting any stimuli. A one-routine-covers-all does not exist within reasonable time constraints.

Comment: Ah yes.  That wasn't clear.  The answer seemed to say that since he uses dumbells, his routine won't workout many muscles.  Perhaps you could edit that lat paragraph to reflect this.

Comment: +1 for highlighting lack of progress without variety.  But aren't isolation exercises considered overall less effective than compound movements?